# Unexpected behavior and compiler error when using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, integer

I'm new to C, and for a few months I've used pointers and tried to figure out how they work and learn syntax for using them, but i ran into a confusing part when compiler throws an error 
`[1]    1473 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out`
but i think code syntax is correct.

Since I am working with and learning about dynamic data structures, a lot of times everything seems fine, but occasionally i end up into some weird errors, so i provided this simple example of using pointers which confuses me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int *b;
  printf ("Enter some int value -> ");
  scanf ("%d", b);

  printf ("Entered value is: %d", *b);


  return 0;
}
```

I am declaring a variable which is pointer to a integer in memory. Since its pointer in scanf() argument is just name of that variable, and when i print it to stdout(printf()) i use *b since pointer to pointer is actual value of that variable.

Comment: `b` is a uninitialized pointer. Derefencing it will cause undefined behavior

Comment: So, what would be the correct syntax for this case?

Comment: One thing you **must** always know about your pointers is **where they point**. In your program, the pointer `b` is uninitialized, so you have no idea where it points to (or whether it's even valid). Try making it point to the middle of an array: `int arr[3]; int *b = &a[1];`. Now you know where it points! You don't know what is in the place `b` points to (or whether it's a valid value), but `b` itself is valid and points to a definite and known place.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - it's not necessary to dereference it to get undefined behaviour.   Accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.   The simple act of passing it by value to a function (by definition) accesses it value.    (A precursor to dereferencing a pointer is also to access its value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*b` is not pointing anywhere. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
  int *b = malloc(sizeof(int)); // dynamically allocate memory
  printf ("Enter some int value -> ");
  scanf ("%d", b);

  printf ("Entered value is: %d", *b);
  free(b); // free the dynamically allocated memory
  return 0;
}
```

Or without dynamic memory allocation by pointing to a variable on the stack instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int a;
  int *b = &a;
  printf ("Enter some int value -> ");
  scanf ("%d", b);

  printf ("Entered value is: %d", *b); // or have a instead of *b
  return 0;
}
```

---

Make sure to consider the warnings that your compiler gives you. Your code will probably trigger a warning about using the uninitialized local variable 'b'. If you didn't get a warning, see if you can configure your compiler to be more strict.

Comment: ... by adding `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compiler flags.